# For-each loop variable

Tags: c#, for-loop

What does ob means in following code - is this same as item?

```
foreach (var item in allItems)
{
    if (excludeItems.Exists(ob => ob.Equals(item)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item {0} excluded",item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ob` is the parameter to the [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). So if you're familiar with anonymous methods, it's like:

```
foreach (var item in allItems)
{
    if (excludeItems.Exists(delegate (string ob) { return ob.Equals(item); })
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item {0} excluded",item);
    }
}
```

That's assuming the type of `ob` should be `string` - it may well not be. That will depend of `excludeItems`, due to generic type inference.

Lambda expressions can be more explicit, so this *could* be written as:

```
if (excludeItems.Exists((string ob) => { return ob.Equals(item); })
```

or

```
if (excludeItems.Exists((string ob) => ob.Equals(item))
```

Basically there are several little shortcuts in lambda expressions for the common case of a single parameter whose type can be inferred, and a return value from a single expression.

Now in this particular case, the delegate created from the lambda expression will be called once for each element in `excludeItems` (in each iteration of the `foreach` loop) and `ob` will have the value of that element, until it finds a value equal to `item` (or runs out of elements).

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful and detailed. I'll read about lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1):

ob means an item in excludeItems